# Hindi fonts not rendered correctly in reportlab generated PDF

Tags: python, fonts, pdf-generation, reportlab, hindi

I am using a simple Python file for generating PDF. The Python output is correct, but the PDF output has that issue:

[image]

This is not the correct format of these Hindi words.

This is the original text: अतिदेय राशि के पुनर्भुगतान हेतु अनुस्मारक

```
fileName = 'MyDoc.pdf'
title = 'श्रीमान मुख्य अभियंता संदर्भ संख्या'

from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("mangal", "Lohit-Devanagari.ttf"))
pdf = canvas.Canvas(fileName)
# ###################################
pdf.setFont('mangal', 36)
pdf.drawCentredString(300, 770, title)
pdf.save()
```

this is the output pdf file: **Lohit-Devanagari.ttf** is unicode font for hindi
[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly the issue is?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with the correctly rendered text? On my device, the two look the same (however I don't know the language and may be missing some details).

Comment: in the device, it's perfectly fine. print statement also returns the correct output. the issue is with pdf output only.

Comment: I understood that. But in order to demonstrate the problem, could you add another screenshot where the text is shown correctly, so that it is easier for readers of this question to see the difference?

Comment: Hi @Sunil Kumar, Did you get the solution for this?

Comment: No @SiddaramH, I didn't get any solution till now.

Comment: Hi @Sunil Kumar, Did you get the solution for this?